# How to remove multiple marker by double tap on it in Offline Map usind OSMDROID?

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I have develop offline map using OSMDROID library, when we tap anywhere on Map that will create marker on it, I just develop code for multiple marker.

we can add multiple marker on map, but I can't find the way to remove the marker by double tap on it,

i.e I create four marker A, B, C, D sequential, Now If I double tap on Marker B, it will be removed from map

Is it feasible ? If yes then how ?
I have used below code for adding and removing marker by tap and double tap on Map

> ```
>   Overlay touchOverlay = new Overlay(this) {
>         ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay = null;
>         @Override
>         protected void draw(Canvas arg0, MapView arg1, boolean arg2) {
>         }
>         @Override
>         public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(final MotionEvent e,
>                 final MapView mpView) {
>             Projection proj = mpView.getProjection();
>             GeoPoint loc = (GeoPoint) proj.fromPixels((int) e.getX(),
>                     (int) e.getY());
>             ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayArray = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
>             OverlayItem mapItem = new OverlayItem("", "", new GeoPoint(
>                     (((double) loc.getLatitudeE6()) / 1000000),
>                     (((double) loc.getLongitudeE6()) / 1000000)));
>             mapItem.setMarker(OfflineMapDemoActivity.this.getResources()
>                     .getDrawable(R.drawable.location_mark));
>             overlayArray.add(mapItem);
>             anotherItemizedIconOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
>                     getApplicationContext(), overlayArray, null);
>             mpView.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
>             mpView.invalidate();
>             return true;
>         }
>         @Override
>         public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e, MapView mpView) {
>             mpView.getOverlays().remove(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
>             mpView.invalidate();
>             return true;
>         }
>     };
> mapView.getOverlays().add(touchOverlay);
> ```

mapView is the Object of BoundedMapView class used in OSMDROID Library

Comment: I am looking for the same answer... Keep me posted..